NFC Tag detected in android shows false
Good Day to everyone.
One problem regarding the above question
What can I do to detect tag without 'false'?
All other function of the application seems to work just fine
'Log.d("YourTag", "NFC tag detected: " + tag.toString());'
Following the above log statement, the tag.toString always shows 'False'
What seems to be the problem??
This is the onNewIntent
  @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Log.d("YourTag", "onNewIntent called");

        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        if (tag != null) {
            processNfcTag(tag);
        } else {
            Log.e("YourTag", "Tag detection failed");
        }
    }

and this is the function for processNfcTag
  private void processNfcTag(Tag tag) {
        NFCTagFlow nfctag = new NFCTagFlow(this);
        FileIO fileIO = new FileIO(this); // Instantiate FileIO
        Log.d("YourTag", "Processing NFC tag");

        int sectorOrPage = 4;

        // RequestA Command
        byte[] requestACommand = {(byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x26}; // Request Idle (Wake up one)
        byte[] requestAResponse = nfctag.sendNFCCommand(tag, requestACommand);
        if (requestAResponse[0] == 0x00) {
            byte[] atqResponse = Arrays.copyOfRange(requestAResponse, 1, 3);
            Log.d("YourTag", "RequestA Command successful. ATQ response: " + Arrays.toString(atqResponse));
        } else {
            nfctag.handleCommandError(requestAResponse[0]);
        }

        // Anticoll Command
        byte[] anticollCommand = {(byte) 0x04}; // Anticollision command
        byte[] anticollResponse = nfctag.sendNFCCommand(tag, anticollCommand);
        byte[] uid = null;

        if (anticollResponse[0] == 0x00) {
            boolean multipleCards = anticollResponse[1] == 0x01;
            uid = Arrays.copyOfRange(anticollResponse, 2, 6); // Extracting UID
            String hexUID = nfctag.asciiToHex(new String(uid, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
            Log.d("YourTag", "Anticoll Command successful. UID: " + hexUID);
        } else {
            nfctag.handleCommandError(anticollResponse[0]);
        }

        if (uid != null) {
            // Select Command (with UID)
            byte[] selectCommand = new byte[uid.length + 1];
            selectCommand[0] = 0x05; // Select Command
            System.arraycopy(uid, 0, selectCommand, 1, uid.length);
            byte[] selectResponse = nfctag.sendNFCCommand(tag, selectCommand);
            if (selectResponse[0] == 0x00) {
                Log.d("YourTag", "Select Command successful. UID: " + Arrays.toString(uid));
            } else {
                nfctag.handleCommandError(selectResponse[0]);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("YourTag", "UID is null, Select Command cannot proceed");
        }

        // Inserted Halt Command
        byte[] haltCommand = {(byte) 0x06}; // Halt command
        byte[] haltResponse = nfctag.sendNFCCommand(tag, haltCommand);
        if (haltResponse[0] == 0x00) {
            Log.d("YourTag", "Halt Command successful");
        } else {
            nfctag.handleCommandError(haltResponse[0]);
        }

        // NFC_ActivateCard Command
        byte[] activateCardCommand = new byte[]{/* Construct according to your parameters */};
        byte[] activateCardResponse = nfctag.sendNFCCommand(tag, activateCardCommand);
        if (activateCardResponse[0] == 0x00) {
            Log.d("YourTag", "NFC_ActivateCard Command successful");
        } else {
            nfctag.handleCommandError(activateCardResponse[0]);
        }

        // NFC_Exchange Command
        byte[] dataToSend = {/* Your data here */};
        byte[] exchangeCommand = new byte[dataToSend.length + 2];
        exchangeCommand[0] = (byte) 0xB5; // Exchange command code
        exchangeCommand[1] = (byte) dataToSend.length;
        System.arraycopy(dataToSend, 0, exchangeCommand, 2, dataToSend.length);
        byte[] exchangeResponse = nfctag.sendNFCCommand(tag, exchangeCommand);
        if (exchangeResponse[0] == 0x00) {
            Log.d("YourTag", "NFC_Exchange Command successful. Data received: " + Arrays.toString(exchangeResponse));
        } else {
            nfctag.handleCommandError(exchangeResponse[0]);
        }

        // Send file to NFC tag
        new Thread(() -> {
            boolean sendResult = nfctag.sendFileToTag(tag, sectorOrPage);
            if (sendResult) {
                Log.d("YourTag", "File sent to tag successfully.");
            } else {
                Log.e("YourTag", "Failed to send file to tag.");
            }
        }).start();

        // Handling NdefMessage if needed
        final Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        final NdefMessage[] ndefMessage = {null};
        if (ndef != null) {
            try {
                ndef.connect();
                ndefMessage[0] = ndef.getNdefMessage();
                ndef.close();
            } catch (IOException | FormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (ndefMessage[0] != null) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                File directory = fileIO.createFile(MainActivity.this);
                if (directory != null) {
                    fileIO.writeDataToFile(directory, ndefMessage[0]);
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        textView3.setText("NFC Message Written to File");
                    });
                } else {
                    Log.e("FileIO", "Directory is null, cannot write to file.");
                }
            }).start();
        } else {
            Log.e("YourTag", "NdefMessage is null");
        }
    }
}


Why are you running all the "Wake up and Anticollision" stuff ? As you are operating on Android this is all done by Android's NFC classes and when you receive a tag (that is not NULL) you can directly work with the NFC tag (usually by assigning the tag to a NFC technology class e.g. NfcA) and run the connect call. In the next steps you are running your commands depending on the NFC tag class.
